# waitForTransform kills node after changing static tf

Tags: ros, c++, transform-listener, tf-static

I am new to programming and robotics and need help solving a problem i just can't solve. I am working on an art project with three ROS robots built by Wheeltec. (https://community.robotshop.com/robots/show/multi-agent-rosbot-system)

#### Problem

My problem is that my node with a `static_tf_broadcaster` and also listens to this static `tf`, dies after I change this static `tf`.  It shows the following message:

```
[ INFO] [1694708256.332757377]: new coordinates callback! //callback of the subscriber listening to new slave coordinates
[ INFO] [1694708256.332880099]: -2.0 0.0 1.0 0.0          //new slave coordinates received
[ INFO] [1694708256.332950395]: static tf broadcast       //static_tf_broadcaster started
[ INFO] [1694708256.333043655]: tf broadcast done         //new static_tf broadcasted
[ INFO] [1694708256.333091914]: slave_position            //you can ignore this. just a function which changes some numbers for mathematical reasons... 
[slave2/slave_tf_listener-16] process has died [pid 3991, exit code -11, cmd /home/wheeltec/wheeltec_robot/devel/lib/wheeltec_multi/slave_tf_listener __name:=slave_tf_listener __log:=/home/wheeltec/.ros/log/2111f8a4-531a-11ee-bcbd-e45f01bb40e1/slave2-slave_tf_listener-16.log].
log file: /home/wheeltec/.ros/log/2111f8a4-531a-11ee-bcbd-e45f01bb40e1/slave2-slave_tf_listener-16*.log
```

#### Code snippet

I have figured out that the following lines are killing the process:

```
listener1.waitForTransform("/base_footprint", "/slave2", ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(3.0)); 
listener1.lookupTransform("/base_footprint",  "/slave2", ros::Time(0), transformSM1);
```

The above lines come right after `/************************************************************************** FORMATION FOLLOWING **************************************************************************/`. Below is the `tf_broadcaster`:

```
void tf_broadcast()
{
  ROS_INFO("static tf broadcast");
  static tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster base_to_slave;
  geometry_msgs::TransformStamped static_TransformedStamped;
  static_TransformedStamped.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  static_TransformedStamped.header.frame_id = "base_footprint";
  static_TransformedStamped.child_frame_id = "slave2";

  static_TransformedStamped.transform.translation.x = slave_x;
  static_TransformedStamped.transform.translation.y = slave_y;
  static_TransformedStamped.transform.translation.z = 0;

  static_TransformedStamped.transform.rotation.x = 0;
  static_TransformedStamped.transform.rotation.y = 0;
  static_TransformedStamped.transform.rotation.z = slave_z;
  static_TransformedStamped.transform.rotation.w = slave_w;

  base_to_slave.sendTransform(static_TransformedStamped);
  ROS_INFO("tf broadcast done");
  slave_position();
}
```

The broadcaster works just fine, and you can also see the `tf` changing in RViz.

#### Detailed explanation

The robots work with a master-slave system. So, the master has a pathfinding node and automatically finds his way when I publish destination coordinates. The slaves orient themselves via the master. I can give them two coordinates, `slave_x` & `slave_y`, which define their relative position to the master, and the `slave_tf_listener` node calculates the `cmd_vel` messages accordingly so they follow the position. For the calculation of the slave velocities, every slave gets a static `tf` according to the coordinates `slave_x` and `slave_y`. Before I meddled with the code, you would choose the coordinates in a launch file to publish the static `tf` via the `tf` package with a `static_tf_broadcaster`. Having only one formation per launch file sucks when you try to make the robots drive an interesting composition for an art performance. Therefore, I put the broadcaster directly into the `slave_tf_listener` and also added a subscriber so I could publish new slave coordinates, and via the callback function, the node would adjust, and a new static tf would be broadcasted. The broadcaster works fine, as I said before and everything is fine when I start the node, but as soon as I change the slave coordinates, the process dies.

#### Complete Code

````
   /**************************************************************************
    作者：pjf && lyk oiihv
    功能：多机编队
    **************************************************************************/
    #include <ros/ros.h>
    #include <tf/transform_listener.h>
    #include <tf2_ros/static_transform_broadcaster.h>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
    #include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
    #include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
    #include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"
    #include <std_msgs/Int32.h>
    #include <std_msgs/String.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int slave_pause = 0;
    int slave_halt = 0;
    
    double e_linear_x = 0;   // Abstand zur Soll-Position X (vorne und hinten)
    double e_linear_y = 0;   // Abstand zur Soll-Position Y (links und rechts)
    double e_angular_z = 0;  // Verdrehung zur Soll-Position
    double angular_turn = 0; // 修正从机运动方向
    
    double slave_x = 0.8;  // X-Koordinaten Sollposition
    double slave_y = -0.8; // Y-Koordinaten Sollposition
    double slave_z = 0.0;  // X-Koordinaten Sollposition
    double slave_w = 1.0;  // Y-Koordinaten Sollposition
    double slave_coordinates[4] = {slave_x, slave_y, slave_z, slave_w};
    
    double max_vel_x = 1.0;      // maximalgeschw. linear
    double min_vel_x = 0.05;     // minimalgeschw. linear
    double max_vel_theta = 1.0;  // maximalgeschw. angular
    double min_vel_theta = 0.05; // minimalgeschw. angular
    
    double k_v = 1; // 调节前后方向偏差时，k_v越大，线速度越大
    double k_l = 1; // 调节左右方向偏差时，k_l越大，角速度越大
    double k_a = 1; // 调节角度偏差时，k_a越大，角速度越大
    
    // transformational related params
    std::string base_frame;
    std::string base_to_slave;
    std::string tf_prefix_;
    
    // main car speed
    float odom_linear_x = 0;
    float odom_linear_y = 0;
    float odom_angular_z = 0;
    /**************************************************************************
    函数功能：底盘运动sub回调函数（原始数据）
    入口参数：cmd_msg  command_recognition.cpp
    返回  值：无
    **************************************************************************/
    void vel_Callback(const nav_msgs::Odometry &msg)
    {
      odom_linear_x = msg.twist.twist.linear.x;
      odom_linear_y = msg.twist.twist.linear.y;
      odom_angular_z = msg.twist.twist.angular.z;
      if (fabs(odom_linear_x) < min_vel_x)
        odom_linear_x = 0;
    }

    void slave_position()
    {
      ROS_INFO("slave_position");
      slave_x = slave_x + slave_y;
      slave_y = slave_x - slave_y;
      slave_x = -(slave_x - slave_y); // setzt master koordinaten als nullpunkt ... wie auch immer das geht
      slave_halt = 0;
    }
    void tf_broadcast()
    {
      ROS_INFO("static tf broadcast");
      static tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster base_to_slave;
      geometry_msgs::TransformStamped static_TransformedStamped;
      static_TransformedStamped.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
      static_TransformedStamped.header.frame_id = "base_footprint";
      static_TransformedStamped.child_frame_id = "slave2";
    
      static_TransformedStamped.transform.translation.x = slave_x;
      static_TransformedStamped.transform.translation.y = slave_y;
      static_TransformedStamped.transform.translation.z = 0;
    
      static_TransformedStamped.transform.rotation.x = 0;
      static_TransformedStamped.transform.rotation.y = 0;
      static_TransformedStamped.transform.rotation.z = slave_z;
      static_TransformedStamped.transform.rotation.w = slave_w;
    
      base_to_slave.sendTransform(static_TransformedStamped);
      ROS_INFO("tf broadcast done");
      slave_position();
    }
    void slave_coordinates_Callback(const std_msgs::String &msg)
    {
      ROS_INFO("new coordinates callback!");
      slave_halt = 1;
      ROS_INFO_STREAM(msg.data);
    
      std::string::size_type sz;
      std::string::size_type sz2;
      std::string::size_type sz3;
    
      slave_x = std::stod(msg.data, &sz);
      slave_y = std::stod(msg.data.substr(sz), &sz2);
      slave_z = std::stod(msg.data.substr(sz + sz2), &sz3);
      slave_w = std::stod(msg.data.substr(sz + sz2 + sz3));
    
      /*
      ROS_INFO("x_coord:%f", slave_x);
      ROS_INFO("y_coord:%f", slave_y);
      ROS_INFO("z_coord:%f", slave_z);
      ROS_INFO("w_coord:%f", slave_w);*/
    
      slave_coordinates[1] = slave_x;
      slave_coordinates[2] = slave_y;
      slave_coordinates[3] = slave_z;
      slave_coordinates[4] = slave_w;
      tf_broadcast();
    }
    
    void slave_pause_Callback(const std_msgs::String &msg)
    {
      if (slave_pause == 1)
      {
        ROS_INFO("slave2 reactivated");
        slave_pause = 0;
      }
      else if (slave_pause == 0)
      {
        ROS_INFO("slave2 paused");
        slave_pause = 1;
      }
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
      ros::init(argc, argv, "wheeltec_multi");
    
      ros::NodeHandle node;
      ros::NodeHandle private_nh("~");
    
      ros::Publisher slave_vel = node.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel_ori", 10); // publish raw data
      ros::Subscriber vel_sub = node.subscribe("/odom", 1, vel_Callback);
      ros::Subscriber slave_coordinates_sub = node.subscribe("/slave2/slave_coord_topic", 1, slave_coordinates_Callback);
      ros::Subscriber slave_pause_sub = node.subscribe("/slave2/pause", 1, slave_pause_Callback);
    
      private_nh.param<int>("multi_mode", multi_mode, 2); // formation mode
      private_nh.param<std::string>("base_frame", base_frame, "base_footprint");
      private_nh.param<std::string>("base_to_slave", base_to_slave, "slave2");
      private_nh.param<double>("slave_x", slave_x, 0.6);
      private_nh.param<double>("slave_y", slave_y, -0.6);
      private_nh.param<double>("max_vel_x", max_vel_x, 1.0);
      private_nh.param<double>("min_vel_x", min_vel_x, 0.05);
      private_nh.param<double>("max_vel_theta", max_vel_theta, 1.0);
      private_nh.param<double>("min_vel_theta", min_vel_theta, 0.05);
      private_nh.param<double>("k_v", k_v, 1);
      private_nh.param<double>("k_l", k_l, 1);
      private_nh.param<double>("k_a", k_a, 1);
    
      double slave_coordinates[2] = {slave_x, slave_y};
    
      // 使用tf_prefix参数将frame_name解析为frame_id
      tf_prefix_ = tf::getPrefixParam(private_nh);
      base_frame = tf::resolve(tf_prefix_, base_frame);
      base_to_slave = tf::resolve(tf_prefix_, base_to_slave);
    
      // intermediate variables
      geometry_msgs::Twist vel_msg;
      double e_angular_x = 0;
      double e_angular_y = 0;
    
      tf_broadcast();
    
      // tf listener creation
      tf::TransformListener listener1, listener2;
      tf::StampedTransform transformSM1, transformSM2; // 中间变量
      geometry_msgs::Pose pose_orien1, pose_orien2;    // 用于获取终端姿态的变量
      tf::Quaternion RQ21, RQ22;                       // 用于获取当前位姿与目标点的欧拉角
      ros::Duration(3.0).sleep();
      // ros::Rate rate(10.0);
      ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(0);
      spinner.start();
    
      while (node.ok())
      {
    
        if (slave_pause == 1)
        {
          ROS_INFO("pause");
          vel_msg.angular.z = 0;
          vel_msg.linear.x = 0;
        }
        else if (slave_halt == 1)
        {
          ROS_INFO("halt");
        }
        else if (slave_pause == 0 && slave_halt == 0)
        {
/**************************************************************************
           FORMATION FOLLOWING
**************************************************************************/
          
            // do tf transformation of the slave to the desired desitnation
            try
            {
              listener1.waitForTransform(base_frame, base_to_slave, ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(3.0));
              listener1.lookupTransform(base_frame, base_to_slave, ros::Time(0), transformSM1);
            }
            catch (tf::TransformException &ex)
            {
              ROS_WARN("%s", ex.what());
              ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
              continue;
            }
    
            double angular_x1, angular_y1, angular_z1;
            pose_orien1.orientation.x = transformSM1.getRotation().getX();
            pose_orien1.orientation.y = transformSM1.getRotation().getY();
            pose_orien1.orientation.z = transformSM1.getRotation().getZ();
            pose_orien1.orientation.w = transformSM1.getRotation().getW();
            tf::quaternionMsgToTF(pose_orien1.orientation, RQ21);           // 终端当前位姿从四元数形式转换为欧拉角形式
            tf::Matrix3x3(RQ21).getRPY(angular_x1, angular_y1, angular_z1); // 读取期望坐标点与从车的相对角度angular_z1
            e_angular_z = angular_z1;
            if (fabs(odom_linear_x / odom_angular_z) < 5.0)
              angular_turn = atan2(slave_y, slave_x + odom_linear_x / odom_angular_z);
            else
              angular_turn = atan2(slave_y, slave_x);
    
            if (fabs(odom_angular_z) > min_vel_theta) // 主车转弯时，从车需要修正前进方向（前进方向为从车运动轨迹圆的切线方向），才能跟随主车运动
            {
              if (slave_x > 0 && slave_y >= 0)
              {
                if (odom_angular_z > 0)
                  e_angular_z = e_angular_z + angular_turn;
                else
                  e_angular_z = e_angular_z - 3.14 + angular_turn;
              }
              else if (slave_x <= 0 && slave_y >= 0)
              {
                if (odom_angular_z > 0)
                  e_angular_z = e_angular_z + angular_turn;
                else
                  e_angular_z = e_angular_z + angular_turn - 3.14;
              }
              else if (slave_x < 0 && slave_y < 0)
              {
                if (odom_angular_z >= 0)
                  e_angular_z = e_angular_z + angular_turn;
                else
                  e_angular_z = e_angular_z + 3.14 + angular_turn;
              }
              else if (slave_x >= 0 && slave_y < 0)
              {
                if (odom_angular_z > 0)
                  e_angular_z = e_angular_z + angular_turn;
                else
                  e_angular_z = e_angular_z + 3.14 + angular_turn;
              }
              if (e_angular_z > 4.71 && e_angular_z < 7.85)
                e_angular_z = e_angular_z - 6.28;
              if (e_angular_z < -4.71 && e_angular_z > -7.85)
                e_angular_z = e_angular_z + 6.28;
            }
            e_linear_x = transformSM1.getOrigin().x(); // x方向的偏差（小车前后方向的偏差）
            e_linear_y = transformSM1.getOrigin().y(); // y方向的偏差（小车左右方向的偏差）
            e_angular_z = e_angular_z;                 // 角度偏差
    
            // printf("Deviation: \n e_linear_x = %f\n e_linear_y = %f\n e_angular_z =%f\n",e_linear_x,e_linear_y,e_angular_z);
    
            // CALCULATE the line speed of the slave
            if (fabs(odom_linear_x / odom_angular_z) < 5.0) // odom_linear_x/odom_angular_z<5.0可视为小车在做非直线的运动
            {
    
              double d_r; // d_r为主车运动半径与期望跟随点的运动半径之差，
              if (slave_x + odom_linear_x / odom_angular_z >= 0)
              {
                d_r = sqrt(pow(slave_x + odom_linear_x / odom_angular_z, 2) + pow(slave_y, 2)) - odom_linear_x / odom_angular_z;
              }
              else
              {
                d_r = -sqrt(pow(slave_x + odom_linear_x / odom_angular_z, 2) + pow(slave_y, 2)) - odom_linear_x / odom_angular_z;
              }
              vel_msg.linear.x = (odom_linear_x + odom_angular_z * d_r) * fabs(cos(e_angular_z)) + k_v * e_linear_x; // 根据v/w=r，其中w从机=w主机，所以
                                                                                                                     //   v从机/w从机=(odom_linear_x+odom_angular_z*d_r) /odom_angular_z=r主车运动半径+d_r = r从车运动半径，符合运动学规律
            }
            else
            {
    
              vel_msg.linear.x = odom_linear_x + k_v * e_linear_x;
            }
    
            float _k_a = k_a;
            float _k_l = k_l;
            if (vel_msg.linear.x < -min_vel_x) // 从车后退时，修正参数的正负值与前进的相反
            {
    
              if (fabs(odom_angular_z) > min_vel_theta)
                _k_a = -k_a; // 直行运动的_k_a参数为正
              _k_l = -k_l;
            }
            // 计算得到从机的角速度
            vel_msg.angular.z = odom_angular_z + _k_l * e_linear_y + _k_a * sin(e_angular_z);
          
        }
        // speed limit
        if (vel_msg.linear.x > max_vel_x)
          vel_msg.linear.x = max_vel_x;
        else if (vel_msg.linear.x < -max_vel_x)
          vel_msg.linear.x = -max_vel_x;
        if (fabs(vel_msg.linear.x) < min_vel_x)
          vel_msg.linear.x = 0;
        if (vel_msg.linear.y > max_vel_x)
          vel_msg.linear.y = max_vel_x;
        else if (vel_msg.linear.y < -max_vel_x)
          vel_msg.linear.y = -max_vel_x;
        if (fabs(vel_msg.linear.y) < min_vel_x)
          vel_msg.linear.y = 0;
        if (vel_msg.angular.z > max_vel_theta)
          vel_msg.angular.z = max_vel_theta;
        else if (vel_msg.angular.z < -max_vel_theta)
          vel_msg.angular.z = -max_vel_theta;
        if (fabs(vel_msg.angular.z) < min_vel_theta)
          vel_msg.angular.z = 0;
    
        slave_vel.publish(vel_msg);
    
        // ros::spinOnce();
        // rate.sleep();
      }
      ros::waitForShutdown();
      return 0;
    };

```
````

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! While I appreciate your detailed explanation of the problem, this post has become too long to read. I tried my best to clean it, but it needs more work from you. I suggest removing unnecessary info and sharing an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to keep the post as short as possible. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details on how to write a good question.

Comment: @ravi thank you very much! yes, it's much better to read now. I will try to create an MWE

Comment: Inside the `void tf_broadcast()` function, you are using `StaticTransformBroadcaster` with `static` keyword. The `StaticTransformBroadcaster` is supposed to set static TF such as, location of a static object. In your case, you should use `tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster`. Please see an example [here](https://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29).

Comment: Ok, tried that. Compiling worked fine. Now when I start the slave it gives me a warning: `[ WARN] [1694767404.413486867]: "slave2" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist.`  umm... so there must be a problem with the naming of the tf, i guess. And when I give new coordinates the process dies the same way as before.

Comment: As I said before, your post is too long to read. The warning you are reporting in your comment is due to the fact that there is no frame having "slave2" as its id. So, please publish it. Meanwhile, you can use [rqt_tf_tree](https://wiki.ros.org/rqt_tf_tree) to visualize your TF tree.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the fast answers. what do you mean by "publish it" exactly? I thought the broadcaster would do the publishing by itself. the tf I try to broadcast is nowhere to be found, I cant find it in the tf tree nor via rostopic echo tf. The weird thing is: when i use the `StaticTransformBroadcaster` it works just fine- I can echo `tf_static` and watch how it changes, also I used the exact same `child_frame_id` and `header.frame_id`. With a `StaticTransformBroadcaster` it works... now with the normal `TransformBroadcaster` the slave won't follow the master both in mode 1 and 2

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem!

A prefix was missing in the `StaticTransformBroadcaster`. The frame_id should be just `footprint` (the masters footprint), but the child_frame_id should not only be `slave2` but `slave2/slave2`.

Then, down below in the main function `listener1` should listen to the frame_id `slave2/footprint` and the child_frame_id `slave2/slave2`.

I would always have one of them wrong while trying to find the right connection.

Now it works like a charm.